# Animação reversa ao tirar mouse

Tags: html, css, animação

Alguém saberia me dizer como faço a animação "ao contrario" quando tirar o mouse? Testem no link abaixo e acho que irão entender. Quando ponho o mouse, a descrição da imagem "desce", queria que quando retirasse o mouse ele "subisse"

https://jsfiddle.net/evy1oLys/

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar *transition* para alterar a altura do elemento no *hover* mais ou menos assim:

```css
.our-works {
    z-index: 1;
}

.item-works {
    z-index: 99999;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 24%;
    height: 8em;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.item-works:hover .sub-works {
    display: inherit;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.item-works:hover .sub-works {
   
   max-height: 150px;
   transition: max-height 0.7s ease;
}

.sub-works {
  transition: max-height 0.7s ease;

    max-height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #00aeff;
    top: 0;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
}

.link-foto {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: .8em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #008bcc;
    font-weight: bolder;
}

.desc-works {
    margin-top: 1em;
    text-align: center;
}

.desc-works p {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.img-works {
    max-width: 100%;   
}
```

```html
<section class="works">
        <div class="container">
           <div class="our-works">
            <h2 class="title-section">Our Works</h2>
            <ul class="list-works">
                <li class="item-works"><img src="image/work1.png" alt="Work" class="img-works">
                    <div class="sub-works">
                        <div class="desc-works">
                        <h2 class="subtitle">Work</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="link-foto">+</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="item-works">
                   <img src="image/work1.png" alt="Work" class="img-works">
                    <div class="sub-works">
                      <div class="desc-works">
                       <h2 class="subtitle">Work</h2>
                       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p> 
                       <a href="#" class="link-foto">+</a>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="item-works"><img src="image/work1.png" alt="Work" class="img-works">
                    <div class="sub-works">
                       <div class="desc-works">
                        <h2 class="subtitle">Work</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="link-foto">+</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="item-works"><img src="image/work1.png" alt="Work" class="img-works">
                    <div class="sub-works">
                       <div class="desc-works">
                        <h2 class="subtitle">Work</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
                        <a href="#" class="link-foto">+</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="item-works"><img src="image/work1.png" alt="Work" class="img-works">
                    <div class="sub-works">
                       <div class="desc-works">
                        <h2 class="subtitle">Work</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="link-foto">+</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="item-works"><img src="image/work1.png" alt="Work" class="img-works">
                    <div class="sub-works">
                       <div class="desc-works">
                        <h2 class="subtitle">Work</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="link-foto">+</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="item-works"><img src="image/work1.png" alt="Work" class="img-works">
                    <div class="sub-works">
                       <div class="desc-works">
                        <h2 class="subtitle">Work</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="link-foto">+</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="item-works"><img src="image/work1.png" alt="Work" class="img-works">
                    <div class="sub-works">
                       <div class="desc-works">
                        <h2 class="subtitle">Work</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="link-foto">+</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Mas aí ele fica sem aquele efeito de "bater e voltar", que era o propósito do uso de keyframes.